# Understanding ACF and PACF graphs

Tags: time-series

I'm new to working with time-series and still have some problems interpreting my results. Specifically, I have three time-series and want to see if they're correlated, i.e. if when one has values increasing, does the other's values increase/decrease concurrently. I don't want to do any forecasting, just analyze how the three time-series correlate with each other.

I know there are many threads here and information on google and I've read through quite a few, but I'm still not sure if I understand it, so I kindly ask for some help with my specific data.

[image: Time-series]

pair-wise ACF:

[image: ACF plots]

and pair-wise PACF:

[image: PACF plots]

Answer (score 1):

The ACF and pACF graphs of a time series are used to explore whether the series are correlated with previous values (lags) of itself. For instance, the TS2 ACF graph shows that there is probably correlation between a value at time $t$ and $t-1$ (the bar extends outside the blue significance threshold). This is some valuable information already.

That being said, if your objective is to see whether the time series correlate with each other why don't you try this:

Use the Spearman's statistic (which is non-parametric as well) to assess (significant) correlations both at the same as well as previous lags. For instance

1. $TS1_{t}$ VS $TS2_{t}$ VS $TS3_{t}$
2. $TS1_{t}$ VS $TS2_{t-1}$ VS $TS3_{t-1}$

and so on. If I were you, I would try the lags that "make sense" ie what do these variables represent plus the ones that are indicated as significant according to your plots.

You can use the `lag` function in R in order to create a matrix with all lagged observations you want to assess and then use `cor.test(x,y method = 'spearman')` to find the significant ones.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into Spearman's statistic. So, you're saying I can't use the pairwise ACF/PACF plots or rather they're not meaningful (as in: do not show what I'm interested in)?

Also, I'm not quite sure I understand the difference between ACF and PACF

Comment: Yes exactly. The way I see it, the ACF and pACF will give you valuable info for each individual TS but I don't personally see a direct way to answer your question about correlations with each other using those two functions. I'm really open to suggestions from other users as well but I think I'm correct. The Spearman statistic on the other hand, should give you the answer you want and I can't think of any objections against it.

Comment: Let me try to give you an intuitive definition of ACF and pACF. The ACF is basically showing you the correlation between observations that are 1,2,3,... lags apart. Let's now assume that (as in the case of TS2) the time series at $t$ is correlated with $t-1$. Then $X_{t-2}$ depends on $X_{t-1}$ that depends on $X_{t}$. That natural question arising is: can the dependence between $X_{t-2}$ and $X_{t}$ be explained by their mutual dependence on $X_{t-1}$? This is the idea of pACF. It's a measure of correlation between two points in time after removing (controlling) all the in-between effects